# simulate click on option and wait for change event to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, html-select

I'm trying to simulate clicks with looping with '.each' jquery function over option elements.

But, this select have an `onchange` function associated which changes a value on another input.

This is my code so far:

```
$('#selectItem').on('change', function() {
  console.log( $('#inputToWatch').val() );
});
$('#selectItem').children().each(function( index ) {
    $( this ).attr('selected', 'selected').parent().focus();
    $( this ).parent().change();
});

/*I also tried this way
$('#selectItem').children().each(function( index ) {
    $( this ).attr('selected', 'selected').parent().focus();
    setTimeout(function(){ $( this ).parent().change(); }, 3000);
    console.log( index + ": " + $('#inputToWatch').val() );
});
*/
```

And html looks like

```
<select id="selectItem" onchange="changeFunc(this)">
   <option value="option1" selected="selected">option1</option>
   <option value="option2" selected="selected">option2</option>
   <option value="option3" selected="selected">option3</option>
   <option value="option4" selected="selected">option4</option>
</select>
```

I'm not being able to make jquery wait until `'changeFunc'` ends to log value of `'#inputToWatch'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#selectItem').children().each(function( index ) {
    $( this ).attr('selected', 'selected').parent().focus();
    $( this ).parent().change();
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction(){
  console.log( $('#inputToWatch').val() );
}
```

If I've understood right, the `myFunction()` will be called after the 2 other manipulations, at the end.

Comment: Yes, you've understood right but, in that way seems like `.change` can't be able to trigger because all logs are identical. But if I manually execute the commands within loop for each child, it focuses right and `.change` call to `onchange function` and then `myFunction` works.